# How can I switch audio track during playback

Tags: html5-video, mpeg-dash

I load content from the following manifest using dash.js into an HTML5 video: [MPD file](http://usp.neonstingray.com/video/13529/13529.ism/Manifest.mpd). It contains one video and four audio tracks. I'm trying to figure out how I can enumerate and enable/disable the different audio tracks available.

I understand that if they were added as `TRACK` elements to the `VIDEO` element I could enable/disable them through `video.audioTracks` but that isn't possible as they are loaded from the manifest.

Any pointers as to how I could solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have found that it's not necessary to have `<track>` elements present at all; with just a `<video>` and `<source>`, I was successfully able to manipulate `video.audioTracks[i].enabled` to switch the audible track as answered by Jeoffrey Mendez. Browser support [is abysmal](https://caniuse.com/#feat=audiotracks), however – still only purportedly supported by Safari and IE derivatives as of February 2018.

Answer (score 2):

```
videoObject.audioTracks[audioTrackIndex].enabled = true;
```

Comment: Although this may solve the issue, always include a description of why what you are proposing will work. Code by itself is not searchable.

Comment: audioTracks is not yet supported by most of the browsers. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get a list of available qualities:

```js
// assuming player is the instance of MediaPlayer
var metricsExt = player.getMetricsExt();
var num_qualities = metricsExt.getMaxIndexForBufferType('audio', 0 /*that's the period index*/);
var qualities = [];
for (var i = 0; i < num_qualities; i++) {
     qualities.push(metricsExt.getBandwidthForRepresentation(i+1));
}
```

And then if the user chooses another quality:

```js
player.setQualityFor('audio', newQualityIdx);
// newQualityIdx is the 0-based index of the chosen quality
```

You may probably also want to turn off `auto-switch-quality` in case the user chooses a quality manually:

```js
player.setAutoSwitchQuality(false);
```

Comment: Thx for the response, but that's not quite what I'm after. I want to choose between the four audio AdaptationSets. As it is now dash.js will pick the first available, which in this case would be Danish (row 16). I haven't found any other way than to intercept the manifest and remove unwanted audio track before feeding it to the player.

Problem is; if I want to change audio track I have to re-parse the manifest which ofc resets the stream :(